# Why do images open with my app in Android Studio but when installed on my phone they hang or wont't open?

Tags: android, android-image

**Scenario:** I have a database oriented app that has stored images in the app's internal Files directory. These images are associated with research notes.

**My Problem:** When I run and test the app in Android Studio all images open without issue. When I installed the app on my phone, everything works but images simply hang (cursor only) with "Photos" app or explanation point (!) image with "Gallery" app.

When selecting the image link in the phone, it prompts to select one of these two apps (Photo or Gallery). The Android Studio emulator simply opens the image and doesn't prompt for a selection.

**What I have done:** I reviewed the coding and tried hard coding the image type, used the `MimeTypeMap` and even removed the mime type designation when using `Intent.setData` or `Intent.setDataAndType` all of which work without issue in the Android Studio.

Both the Android Studio Pixel emulator and the Samsung A10e have Android 9. I'm not sure what else may be beneficial and helpful. Let me know if anything and I will provide it.

**The code used**

```java
private void openFile(Uri uri, String mime){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri,mime);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid but I solved my problem. I had the createFiles() off after creating files with Android Studio when testing how to open them. However, when I pushed my app to the phone, I forgot to turn this method back on. This was why it didn't work.

The above code does work correctly.